# What is "affine space generated by two affine subspaces"?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $(X,\vec X,+)$ a real affine space, $a\in X, b\in X, \vec A $ and $\vec B$ two subspaces of $\vec X$.

$A=a+\vec A$ and $B= b+\vec B$ two affine subspaces.

I want to understand what the "affine subspace generated by $A$ and $B$" is, because Jean Frenkel speaks of it in *Géométrie pour l'élève professeur*(Geometry for student professeur). He notes it $$V(A\cup B)$$

If $A\cap B \neq \emptyset$, no problem : let $c\in A\cap B, V(A\cup B)=c+(\vec A+\vec B)$. For example, in affine space $(\mathbb R^3,\mathbb R^3,+) $, if $A$ and $B$ are two lines intersecting in $c$,  that seems like a perfectly reasonable definition.

*On the other hand, if these two lines have nothing in common, I don't know what it is.*

Frenkel talks about it at the beginning of his book about the incidences between affine subspaces; He is interested in the dimension of $V(A\cup B)$.

Here's what he writes in the event that $A\cap B=\emptyset$:

$\vec A, \vec B, \vec {ab}\in \overrightarrow{V(A\cup B)}$
, so $\vec A+\vec B+\mathbb R\vec{ab}\subset \overrightarrow{V(A\cup B)}$.Furthermore, $A\cup B\subset a+(\vec A+\vec B+\mathbb R\vec{ab})$ since $A=a+\vec A, B=a+\vec{ab}+\vec B$. So, $\overrightarrow{V(A\cup B)}\subset \vec A+\vec B+\mathbb R \vec{ab}$

*I'm coming to the end of writing my post and I'm thinking that in fact, maybe I've finally understood:*
$$\boxed{\text{If }A\cap B=\emptyset, V(A\cup B)=a+\vec A+\vec B+\mathbb R\vec{ab}}$$
*I tell myself that I'm doing the post anyway because, since Frenkel's text is excessively technical, I took some liberties with it. Perhaps then I will be given some useful constructive criticism.*

---

- Note that Frenkel did not define the notion before his proof, which surprised me in a text of such quality.
- If I understand correctly, going back to two non-intersecting lines $A$ and $B$ of space, $V(A\cup B)$ is the whole space.
- Finally, the missing definition in Frenkel's book would be the smallest affine subspace containing $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @coffeemath: where did I miss arrows ?

Comment: I would expect it to be the smallest affine subspace containing the two. In the case of non-intersecting lines, consider whether the lines are parallel or not.

Comment: @blargoner : yes. I had in mind two non-parallel lines, but you're right to point that out. Thank you.